# How to make a React Modal Component that works in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, storybook

Could you help me giving me some ideas of how to implement a ModalBox that works in storybook and algo that could be implement as if it was a library component ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got it, but the code below might be useful. And in this case, the `ModalComponent` could come from any UI library.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import ModalComponent from '.';

export default {
  title: 'Components/Modal',
  component: ModalComponent
} as ComponentMeta<typeof ModalComponent>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof ModalComponent> = (args) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Click to open modal</button>
      <ModalComponent
        isOpen={isOpen}
        handleClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      >
        {args.children}
      </ModalComponent>
    </>
  );
};

export const Modal = Template.bind({});

Modal.args = {
  children: 'Content'
};
```